# Portfolio optimization in MATLAB with volatility (quadratic) and integer weight (discrete) constraints

Tags: algorithm, matlab, linear-programming, quantitative-finance

I have a time series of returns and need to find weights that maximize portfolio returns, subject to the constraints that volatility not exceed 5% and that constituent weights are integer-based (0%, 1%, 2%, etc.).

I want to perform this optimization in MATLAB, but I can't think of a function that will accommodate these constraints.
**`fmincon()`** will address the quadratic constraint, but requires that the constraints be continuous, so it won't handle the discrete allocation constraints.
**`intlinprog()`** will work for the integer constraints but not for the quadratic constraint.

I'm aware of mixed integer linear programming in MATLAB, particularly the genetic algorithm.  But I wouldn't know where to get started as far as how to write the code.

Comment: The easiest would be to use a MINLP or MIQP solver. Matlab does not have this out of the box, so one would have to use an external solver. The other way is as you indicated use a meta-heuristic (e.g genetic algorithm). That requires some more work (and you may loose some optimality guarantees). A final note: [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/02/cardinality-constrained-portfolio.html) is a heuristic to approximate an MIQP problem by solving successive MIP problems.

Comment: Would asking you to produce the objective function and the constraints be asking too much? I know that StackOverflow does not allows LaTeX (which is a shame), but you can LaTeX the optimization problem on Math Stack Exchange and then post a print-screen here.